# Ifelse Nested within If resulting in Expected Command Error

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to get a certain breed of turtles to lay down more or less chemical than the base amount depending on food-quality, a patch variable randomly set from 0.2 - 1. Prior to addition of the asterisked code, it worked fine. How can I make this work? Thanks!

```````````
to pickup-food
if food > 0
  [set color violet
   set food food - 1]
if color = violet
   [facexy nest-x nest-y
    jump 2
    set chemical chemical + 60
  **[ifelse food-quality > 0.6
     [set chemical chemical + 90]  ;; drop some chemical
     [set chemical chemical + 30]]**
  ]
 if (distancexy 25 14) < 2
  [face patch food-x food-y
    fd 3]
end
``````````
```````````

Answer (score 1):

the `ifelse` condition should not be in brackets, just the actions to be taken. You want:

```
ifelse food-quality > 0.6
[ set chemical chemical + 90 ]
[ set chemical chemical + 30 ]
```